# Why when I press bloc num, my linux writes on disk?

Tags: arch-linux, logs, keyboard

When I enable or disable the [Bloc Num](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocco_numeri), my Archlinux writes something on disk. I can't understand what it saves, probably it's logging, but I can't find nothing in logs. And also, why should it log these actions?

This doesn't happen with caps lock or other key.

Comment: You Num Lock to have the numeric keypad write numbers or cursor keys? Or any key on the number block?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to explain **how it is that you know** that "something" is being written to disc.

Comment: Very simple: the hdd light blinks and a small noise caused by hard disk's head positioning. This happens immediately after I press the num lock key :)

Comment: Nothing to do with logs. Some DEs (e.g. GNOME) save the _numlock_ state in a database which is a binary file in GNOME so, obviously, changing the content of such files results in disk writes.